# How to remove unused library declaration

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am a newbie in Netbeans. So forgive me for trivial questions and if the question's title is misleading.

I am using Netbeans for PHP development.
Netbeans version 7.1
OS Windows XP

In my project directory structure we are having library/Zend and library/Zend_old two folders. Now when I Ctrl + Click on any method. I get two options of the declaration. One is in Zend folder and second is in Zend_old folder. We are not using Zend_old folder any more. So how can I tell netbeans to ignore Zend_old folder completely ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you added the libraries. Go to Project Properties -> Libraries. Look at the libraries listed there (click edit to see the specific paths used by each library). Remove the one for Zend_old.

If that doesn't do the trick, go to Tools -> Libraries. If you setup a library folder for your project, you will need to change the 'Libraries location' pull down to the library directory for your project rather than the global one. Look through the libraries listed there and find the one that references Zend_old, and remove it (using the button below the list of libraries, not the one to the right of the library properties).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no option to remove it.Here is a bug report https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=214239 and answer from netbeans forum http://forums.netbeans.org/topic70

Comment: That bug is about changing where your library definitions are saved; if you set up a project-specific libraries folder, you can't go back to using global libraries. However, regardless of where your library definitions are saved, you can always add or remove individual libraries from that list without problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Search libraries in the search field (cmd + i) this will show you all libraries in your gobal libraries, select your librarie that you need to remove, then remove and then ok.